# AppDelegate not showing Storyboard buttons

Tags: swift, uibutton, storyboard, appdelegate

I am setting up a MainViewController holding multiple ViewControllers the following way:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let pageController = UIPageViewController(
            transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.scroll,
            navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.horizontal,
            options: nil
        )

        let navigationController = MainViewController(rootViewController: pageController)
        navigationController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let leftView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC1")
        let middleView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2")
        let rightView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC3")

        navigationController.viewControllerArray = [leftView, middleView, rightView]

        self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
}
```

My MainViewController also has what is supposed to be a floating button. I have aded this in the storyboard (see picture below). The problem is that the button is not showing. How do i make it show?
I know that somehow this problem is related to the fact that I adding MainViewController in the AppDelegate, but I am not sure how that is hiding the buttons.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't creating your `MainViewController` instance from the storyboard, you are just creating it with a call to its initialiser.  This means that none of your storyboard elements will be loaded

You need something like:

```
let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main")
navigationController.viewControllers = [pageController]
```

Comment: you are correct, I had the feeling this was the case. But the problem is not, how to set up the rootViewController? In other words how do I replace this part '(rootViewController: pageController)'

Comment: Add your `pageController` to the storyboard.  You can then get a reference to it in the `prepareForSegue` function in your navigation controller